# Organizar la base de datos para la consulta

Tags: php, mysql

¡Muy buenas! Intentaré ser específico y breve a la vez :)

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación amateur empleando Bootstrap para hacer un seguimiento en la producción casera de queso. Durante el proceso el queso va pasando de una habitación a otra. En una tabla mysql añado con un formulario cada lote, con la fecha de inicio, kilogramos, ingredientes, etc.

Para mí son muy importantes las observaciones del proceso, así que quiero generar un informe de cada lote en el que me muestre los datos de cada lote, las fechas en que cambié de habitación, y las observaciones recogidas. Pero es posible que en la habitación 1 tenga una observación el día 18 de julio, y otra el 20 de julio. Pero sólo tengo una columna llamada observaciones.

Quisiera vuestras opiniones para ver cómo organizar los datos para emitir y mostrar las consultas de la manera más fácil, porque me apasiona programar, pero no es mi actividad principal, por lo que no quiero empezar organizando mal la base de datos.

Después de consultar varias respuestas aquí, he pensado:

- Opción 1:

  - Creo un formulario exclusivo para generar observaciones, en el que se indica la habitación, fecha y comentario.
  - Al enviar los datos a la tabla, creo columnas como comentario1, fecha1, habitación1.
  - Si agrego más observaciones, se añadirían otras tres columnas: comentario2, fecha2, habitación1. Es decir, de forma consecutiva (no sé cómo hacerlo, la verdad).
  - Cuando genero la consulta busco, para cada habitación, los comentarios y fechas y los muestro.
- Opción 2:

  - Cada vez que en la tabla con todos los lotes inserte un lote nuevo, creo una tabla independiente para ese lote.
  - Esa nueva tabla incluiría una columna con la fecha de cada comentario, y otra para las observaciones recogidas.
  - Cuando haga la consulta, para ese lote extraigo de la segunda tabla los datos de la siguiente manera: si el lote estuvo en una habitación en un intervalo de fechas, muestro para ese lote todas las observaciones, con sus fechas.
- Opción 3:

  - Utilizar concat para ir añadiendo al campo comentarios de cada lote, cada una de las observaciones por fecha.
  - Es decir, en un formulario recojo la fecha de la observación (y la convierto a texto), el texto de la observación, y ambos los introduzco en el campo comentarios de esa habitación, separándolos por ejemplo con un salto de línea. De esta opción me preocupa que quede bien expresada en la consulta posterior.

Uff, al final me ha salido un tocho, disculpad. Prefería consultar antes de comenzar a programar a lo loco.

¿Qué os parecen las opciones? ¿Alguna otra idea?
¡Muchísimas gracias!
Alex.

Comment: Más o menos estas tablas: **`tbl_lotes`** con las columnas (`id_lote, fecha_creacion, ...`),  **`tbl_observaciones`** con (`id_observacion, fecha, id_lote, ¿id_habitacion?...`), **`tbl_control`** con (`id, id_lote, id_habitacion, fecha_entrada, fecha_salida...`),  **`tbl_habitaciones`** con (`id_habitacion, ubicacion...`). Luego relacionas lo que tengas que relacionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, estás empezando tu diseño, por lo tanto eres libre en cuanto a la forma en que quieres implementarlo.

Te recomendaría que pienses los elementos de tu sistema como entidades independientes y que luego pienses en las relaciones.

¿Qué *entidades* habría?

- lotes
- habitaciones
- observaciones
- ... otras

Puedes tener una tabla por cada una de esas entidades.

#### `lotes`

Con las columnas:

```
id_lote
fecha_creacion
... etc
```

#### `habitaciones`

Con las columnas:

```
id_habitacion
nombre
lugar
...etc
```

#### `observaciones`

Con las columnas:

```
id_observacion
observacion
```

Esta tabla `observaciones` puede ser tratada como una *entidad*, por ejemplo, en el caso de que haya observaciones que se repiten con muchísima frecuencia.

En el caso de que no convenga tratarla como entidad, porque es difícil estandarizar las observaciones que ocurren o por otros motivos, esta tabla debería tener las columnas `id_lote`, `id_habitacion`, `fecha` y la tabla `lotes_observaciones` indicada más abajo no sería necesaria.

Ya tenemos las entidades.

---

Ahora es posible que necesitemos algunas tablas para establecer relaciones entre ellas.

Para controlar la entrada y salida de lotes en las habitaciones:

#### `lotes_habitaciones`

```
id (autoincremental)
id_lote
id_habitacion
fecha_entrada
fecha_salida
```

Para controlar las observaciones hechas sobre los lotes:

#### `lotes_observaciones`

```
id (autoincremental)
id_lote
id_observacion
id_habitacion  (si se requiere saber en qué habitación ocurrió la observación)
fecha
```

Luego, para presentar los datos... es lo de menos. Se harían las uniones de lugar (JOIN) y listo.

Comment: Muy interesante tu respuesta, Cedano. No conocía las entidades. Voy a ponerme con ellas y a comparar tu estructura con lo que había pensado. ¡Un saludo y gracias por tu respuesta tan completa!

Answer (score 2):

No.. ninguna de las 3..

Podría decirte porque son malas (muy) cada una de las 3.. pero primero resolvamos tu problema..

Si tenes las habitaciones, solo necesitas una tabla que diga el numero de habitación, la fecha y el comentario.

El comentario no debe ir en la tabla principal, debe ir en una tabla secundaria, para ser consultado por fecha o por habitación.

tenes una relación 1:muchos, donde por cada habitación, tenes N comentarios.

---

Explicación larga de porque no cada una de las cosas que decís:

opción 1: no se deben alterar las tablas del sistema, si no se altera el sistema. Agregar columnas a las tablas no genera mas datos, genera lio.. que pasa cuando lleguemos al comentario 100, y la tabla no nos deje agregar mas columnas?? como sabemos cuantas columnas tenemos para ir a buscar ahi la información???

opción 2: una tabla nueva, llamada tablalote1, tablalote2.. otra vez.. y en la tablalote1543, no vamos a saber donde estamos parados.. la base se arma y se deja armada como esta, con las columnas y tablas necesarias para contener los datos.

opción 3: esta no seria tan mala, salvo que para hacer búsquedas vas a tener que recorrer todo el texto. y puede que tu campo tenga un máximo de caracteres, salvo que lo hagas binario, y ahí no vas a poder buscar nada salvo trayendolo todo y traduciéndolo a texto.